# Game Maker Studio 2 get_string deprecated

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

I am trying to ask the user for a name to put into my highscore table.

I do not want to use get_string_async because then it adds a the name and score before the user has even given a name, however get_string does not work because it is deprecated.

```
name = get_string("Game Over. What is your name?","Player");
highscore_add(name,score);
global.highscore == 1; //tells draw event to draw highscore table.
```

Is there an alternative to get_string that waits for input before continuing through the code?

Comment: I thought I would have made use of the KeyUp event, but I don't think that works well for every single key.

Comment: Don't user `get_string` or `get_string_async`, it's for debug only. Go to Marketplace and get any free GUI or textbox (text input) and use it.

Comment: I am a sub account as part of my school, and I can't buy assets.

Comment: The Key event idea could work. I could use a KeyDown any, then add that key to a string. Then add the string to the highscore table when the user presses Enter. The only thing is i'm not sure if there is a way to find the string value of the key that is pressed. Edit: I can use keyboard_string to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the player to type in their own name, try setting something up where, when you first start typing it does

you can put this into a script, and say:

```
name = scr_get_name();


//Inside of "scr_get_name()"
keyboard_string = 0;
if(player_typing){
    if(keyboard_check_pressed(vk_enter)){
        name = keyboard_string;
        return(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing something like this.